# Post again after login with cookie received

Tags: java, android

I am working on a login service that logs a user in then after a successful login it posts again to a new script with a cookie that was given on the login to get more info. here is my login post:

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://testsite.com/login");

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "john"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "test"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String TAG = "com.imtins.worryfree";
                String responseAsText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                Log.d(TAG, "Response from server: " + responseAsText.toString());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
```

Now from what ive read if I use the same hpptClient without starting a new one, when i do another post it will use the cookie that i recieved? where could I add a second post in my example or how would it look. Just getting started with android/Java so this is a little confusing for me.

Thanks.

Comment: within the same method after httpclient.execute(httppost);  you can create another httppost object and fire httpclient.execute() again

Comment: @Gaurav Can you show me how that would look and I will accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an HttpContext + CookieStore to keep track of cookie state between requests.  I think something like this would work for you (untested):

```
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://testsite.com/login");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", "john"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "test"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);
            String TAG = "com.imtins.worryfree";
            String responseAsText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            Log.d(TAG, "Response from server: " + responseAsText.toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

And for your 2nd request, reuse the localContext variable:

```
        // replace XXX below with correct URL
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://testsite.com/XXXXXX");

        try {
            // set entities here ...

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);
            String TAG = "com.imtins.worryfree";
            String responseAsText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            Log.d(TAG, "Response from server: " + responseAsText.toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```